# Changing GPS tracker symbol

Tags: qgis, symbology, gps

As the title suggests, how can I change the GPS tracker symbol in QGIS desktop?
Little explanation: I connected a GPS to my QGIS trough a COM port, the position is showed accurately on the map, but it has a default symbol as a marker.
I want to change the default (black circle with inner cross) to my own marker (a boat).

Haven't found it out yet how to do this.. Hope somebody knows this!

Comment: In which software? Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: I edited my comment!